# How to create a running total in Power BI DAX with 3 filter critera?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this formula creating the cumulative 'Target Cost'.

Target Cost Actuals YTD =
CALCULATE(
SUM('Combined Usage'[TargetCost]),
FILTER(
ALLSELECTED('Combined Usage'[MonthNum]),
ISONORAFTER('Combined Usage'[MonthNum], MAX('Combined Usage'[MonthNum]), DESC)
)
)

I want to create the running cost as per AWS and as per Azure, and also per businessUnit, 1,2 & 3.

I'm aware I can add visualisation level filters perhaps for the business units, but I initially need to split the target cost by AWS and Azure.

How do I add a filter into this DAX to also filter where Source = AWS?

**Target Cost Actuals YTD =
CALCULATE(
SUM('Combined Usage'[TargetCost]),
FILTER(
ALLSELECTED('Combined Usage'[MonthNum]),
ISONORAFTER('Combined Usage'[MonthNum], MAX('Combined Usage'[MonthNum]), DESC)
)
)**

Is there a way to then add in another filter that says AND business unit = "1"?

Thank you!

Here is some demo data:

[image]

I would like my calculation to give me a running total where source = AWS and Business unit = 1.

So in monthnum 1 the total = 4.50.

In monthnum 2 the total would be the previous months 4.50 + this months 3.00 = 7.50

In month num 3 the total would be 7.50 + 0.00 = 7.50

Thanks

Comment: please share some sample data and expected result accordingly...

Comment: Thanks - I have shared some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `&&` in the filter

```
    Target Cost Actuals YTD =
    CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Target Cost] ),
    'Table'[Business Unit] = 1
        && 'Table'[Source] = "AWS",
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[Monthnum] ),
        ISONORAFTER ( 'Table'[Monthnum], MAX ( 'Table'[Monthnum] ), DESC )
    )
)
```

[this is the sample file if you need](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MQdkvXgq1jNQm_iW8JWd4cC02gfIeeq/view?usp=sharing)

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I get an error. **"A single value for column 'Source' in table 'Combined Usage' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contain many values without specifying an aggregation such as min,max..."**

Comment: If i put a max statement like so : 

 && 'Combined Usage'[Source] = "AWS", MAX('Combined Usage'[Source]), DESC

I get error:
**"Too many arguments were passed to the FILTER function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2."**

Comment: @Becca please provide sample data or you can search for ** [dax filter with multiple criterias](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/specifying-multiple-filter-conditions-in-calculate/)

Comment: I have added an example. Please could you help?

Comment: @Rebecca revised my answer, please check...

Comment: @Rebecca anytime  please accept as an answer ;)

Comment: When I change the month axis to 'monthnum', instead of hierarchy, the cumulative line ends up just a line (it decreases and increases). Have you come across this before?

Comment: Yet I need it to be in hierarchy so I can add trend lines?

Comment: @Rebecca ask it as a separate question please

Comment: Hey, I've looked into this some more and it's actually not working. Ignore my comments from 30th, no matter whether the date axis is date or date heirarchy, if I plot my line it still increases and decreases. Can you help?

Comment: @Rebecca for the sample data you've given, it is working, if you supply the sample data which is not working, we can check again...